# Bash column dependant average

Tags: linux, bash, awk, average

***This is a repeated Question:** [calculate and print the average value of strings in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357707/calculate-and-print-the-average-value-of-strings-in-a-column)

I have a file with two columns:

```
9       152
391     576
391     104
391     335
391     129
391     280
394     184
394     64
394     313
394     159
394     335
394     159
394     66
394     435
394     145
450     318
450     131
450     131
```

(actual is several thousand lines)

And I'm trying to produce an average for each number on the left, the output I'm looking for would be(keeping to one decimal place):

```
9     152
391   284.8
394   206.6
```

I've come as far to know the solution is an awk command, perhaps also using uniq, that is as far as I got.

Another file needing the same:

```
2014-05-10 23:50        335
2014-05-10 23:50        134
2014-05-10 23:50        134
2014-05-10 23:50        610
2014-05-10 23:50        131
2014-05-10 23:50        315
2014-05-10 23:50        131
2014-05-10 23:50        1055
2014-05-10 23:50        315
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awk way without arrays presuming all numbers are grouped

```
 awk 'x~/./&&x!=$1{printf "%d\t%.1f\n",x,y/z;y=z=""}
      {x=$1;z++;y+=$2}END{printf "%d\t%.1f\n",x,y/z}' file

9       152.0
391     284.8
394     206.7
450     193.3
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly, however when I tried to use it for another file it does not work, where can I alter it so that it works on other files, for example:
2014-05-10 23:50        131
2014-05-10 23:50        1055
2014-05-10 23:50        315

Comment: @user3770935 I have no idea, is that one line or more. Post it in the question.

Comment: @user3770935 Do you understand how the command i posted worked ? Or even how awk works ?

Comment: Not to such a degree as your command

Comment: @user3770935 Wouldn't it be better to understand how it works rather than just get one off answers ?

Comment: If you could explain the intricacies of the command you kindly provided I and others can apply to our own problems

Comment: Note this particular recipe will only work when the file being read is already sorted on the first column. If that is not the case, then you need the approach in the answer by @TomFenech

Comment: @twalberg As i stated in my answer `if all numbers are grouped`, and it doesn't need sorting, they just need to be grouped as i said.Even if they weren't you could sort and then pipe into awk, you could use Toms answer but would not NEED to.

Comment: @JID, any chance of you explaining your solution and how it works?

Comment: @user3770935 Yes if you had asked politely.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]+=$2;++c[$1]}END{for(i in a)printf "%d\t%.1f\n", i, a[i]/c[i]}' file
391     284.8
394     206.7
9       152.0
450     193.3
```

The array `a` keeps a separate sum for each number in the first column. `c` keeps a count of how many rows have contributed to each average. Once the file is processed, the mean for each number in the first column is printed. The format specifier `%.1f` prints the averages, correct to 1 decimal place.

Note that the order of keys in the array `a` is undefined, so the output is in a different order to the input. It's easy enough to get around that issue if necessary.

Comment: How could I get around that? These are to used as x and y coordinates so long as it still produces the same data it doesn't matter much

Comment: The answer depends on which version of awk you're using. GNU awk has some [additional features to control the order of array traversal](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal), or you could just keep track of the order yourself. I'm a little confused by your comment, though. Does it matter to you or not?

Comment: so long as the average remains next to number it correlates to then all if great. Although when run:
awk '{a[$1]+=$2;++c[$1]}END{for(i in a)printf "%d\t%.1f\n", i, a[i]/c[i]}' time_bytes.out > avgTimeBytes.out
Killed

It is killed, or takes up all reseources and locks me out. Is this a problem with the awk command, the file is rather large but other awk opperations have worked in the past, never killed.

Comment: @user3770935 the order in which the results appear is undefined but the keys and values will match up correctly.

Comment: @user3770935 it depends how large we're talking here - if the number of different values in the first column is so large that the array `a` consumes all the available memory in the system, then you will run into problems. If this is the case and the input data is sorted, then you would be better off using a method that didn't use an array.